# FilePickerFileType Unit Tests throw exception NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, maui

I created a custom control in MAUI named FilePicker with a property type of Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePickerFileType. The control and the property works well in each platform, but I did an Unit test for this property.
The Code for test is this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetFilterPicker()
    {
      MyNamespace.FilePicker fp = new MyNamespace.FilePicker();
      fp.Filter = FilePickerFileType.Images;
      Assert.AreEqual( FilePickerFileType.Images, fp.Filter );

    }
```

But this error is throwed:
Test method MyNamespace.UnitTests.FilePicker.FilePickerTests.SetFilterPicker threw exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePickerFileType' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.